# pass variable thru windows form

Tags: vb.net

I just want to pass some value to another form and the current form to close,

This is what I have

--Form1--

```
Private Sub cmdCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdCreate.Click
    Form2.cmdCreate.PerformClick()
    Form2.txtbox1.text = "Something"
    Form2.Show()

    Me.Dispose()
End Sub
```

What's happening is that Form2 it Opens and Close instantly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your projects settings may be set to close when Form1 closes rather than close when the last form closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created this in form2

```
Public Sub New(ByVal Val1 As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    ...
End Sub
```

and add a button with DialogResult set to OK

In form1 use this

```
Dim Dialog As New form2("SomeString")
Dim Result As DialogResult = Dialog.ShowDialog(Me)

If Result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
   ...
End If
```

Form2 will recive "SomeString" in the Val1 parameter =3

Answer (score -1):

you need to set parent of Form2 to the parent of Form1 `Form2.Parent = Me.ParentForm`